# removing path prefix from find results

Tags: shell, find, gnu-findutils

At the simplest, if I execute

`find . -type f -exec cp {} /new/path/{}`

The path that is expanded is /new/path/./path/to/file. I would like to remove that ./ that is prefixed by the find command before I use {} in the exec.

I am using the builtin Freebsd find, but I do have access to gnufind if that will help (though I do not normally use gnufind).

Comment: Why remove it?  It shouldn't harm anything.

Comment: In the stripped down example, no. But for what I need, the ./ is a problem. It's not important, looping the find works.

Answer (score 0):

Where you will have a problem is when find descends into subdirectories, and it tries to exec something like `cp ./foo/bar.txt /new/path/./foo/bar.txt` and "/new/path" has no subdirectory "foo" -- you might want to:

- specify `-maxdepth 1` so you do not descend into subdirs

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} /new/path/{} \;
  ```
- just use a directory destination for `cp`, so the files end up in a single dir (will suffer from collisions if you have "./foo/bar.txt" and "./qux/bar.txt")

  ```
  find . -type f -exec cp -t /new/path {} +
  ```
- use `tar` to copy the whole tree: this will preserve directory structure

  ```
  tar cf - . | ( cd /new/path && tar xvf - )
  ```

Comment: I stripped the example down as much as possible, but none of these solutions work for what I need. I need to eliminate the './' prefix that find places in {}. The only way I can see to do it is to do something like `for i in find....; do <remove the characters>; <do stuff>; done ` but that is less than ideal for my needs. If it's not possible, that's fine, I'll figure out something else.

Comment: @lbutlr You stripped down the question to the point where it's unclear. `find . -type f -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0 ...` might work, but I really have no idea

Comment: @lbutlr Also `for i in $(find ...)` is extremely error prone, if looping you want something like `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' i; do <remove the characters>; <do stuff>; done`